# How to identify java card protocol (T=0 or T=1) using java card technology?

Tags: java, credit-card, javacard, apdu

I used following in the code to connect card and get channel

```
card = terminal.connect("T=1");
channel = card.getBasicChannel();
```

Here T=1 i.e. protocol is hardcoded. Is there any way from which we can find protocol of the card inserted in card reader ?

javacard.framework.APDU has method getProtocol() but I want protocol at the time of [connecting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/package-summary.html) with card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the javadoc of [CardTerminal.connect(String protocol)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/CardTerminal.html#connect(java.lang.String))

> **protocol** - the protocol to use ("T=0", "T=1", or "T=CL"), or "*" to
>   connect using any available protocol.

So it looks like you could use the wildcard.

Comment: Or he can use `try .... catch`. _T=1_ is the newest. So he can try _T=1_ and if failed, try _T=0_ and then _T=CL_.